# Centering images within 300 px by 300 px table grid

Tags: html, css, html-table, centering

My code is below and I'm looking for the best way via CSS to center an image (horizontally and vertically) in a 300 by 300 pixel square. Larger images will be fit down to that size and smaller images should be centered, not stretched.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="300box"><img class="centeredimage" /></div></td>
    <td><div class="300box"><img class="centeredimage" /></div></td>
    <td><div class="300box"><img class="centeredimage" /></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.300box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.centeredimage {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I know the above is incorrect so I'm hoping to find a more efficient way to do it. Each table row has 3 300x300 pixel divs with images centered within.

Comment: Here you have some solutions, although I'm not sure if you will be able to implement them: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: Do you need the `div` to wrap around the `img`? You could add the `vertical-align` and `text-align` to the `td` and that should do it.

Comment: Also, class names shouldn't begin with a number try `.box300` instead

Comment: Ditch both the div and image class, and apply both the .300box and the .centeredimage styles to your <td> directly...

Comment: This technique does not work, the images are centered horizontally but not vertically. It's the vertical part that doesn't seem to stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a div inside a td is not worse than any other way of using tables.

You can try this--

CSS:

```
.blocks.table td {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
p.centeredimage img {
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" class="table blocks">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="centeredimage" ><img src = "http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185106_431273290248855_254736287_n.jpg" /></p>
        </td>

        <td>
            <p class="centeredimage" ><img src = "http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/304640_10151181184992355_456123210_n.jpg" /></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="centeredimage" ><img src = "http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s480x480/422953_410146439043183_1035950087_n.jpg" /></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="centeredimage" ><img src = "http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s480x480/561574_467101546644877_728463753_n.jpg" /></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is good, thanks. But now if I want to add a block of text below each image, if the image is smaller than 300px the text will show up right below the image. How would I do it so that all the text for the images are forced to the bottom of the table cell?

Answer (score 0):

Leave your code exactly the same, change this one style definition:

```
.centeredimage {
  margin: auto;
}
```

And you say that you want larger images to be forced to be no larger than 300 pixels? I know that the max-width attribute sometimes works (but of course IE8 dislikes it immensely), but I don't know how well it works on images (haven't ever tested it myself) but to add that, you'd just add max-width: 300px to your centeredimage class.

Upon reflection, what some other folks said applies as well: apply your .300box class to the td, and get rid of the divs. For what you're describing, they're not necessary.

Comment: This technique does not work, the images are centered horizontally but not vertically. It's the vertical part that doesn't seem to stick.

Comment: Is it possible to attach a screenshot? And: for vertical centering, you want each image to be centered in its table cell, and the images may be of different sizes in that row, correct?